# Sitecore 8.1: Custom Search Index not searching through PDF

Tags: pdf, search, indexing, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a custom search index that I want to index pdf file content. The master index seems to be indexing pdf files fine and sitecore's built in search functionality searches through the pdf files perfectly fine. I seem to be having an issue on trying to index the PDF field and then search the contents of it.

In my indexConfiguration i add the filed by name

```xml
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
  <field fieldName="publication pdf" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
    ...
</fieldNames>
```

My results Item contains index field definition

```cs
[IndexField("publication pdf")]
public virtual string PDF { get; set; }
```

However when I create search context and try to find something inside the PDF, i get 0 results.

```cs
var query = context.GetQueryable<ResultItem>();
query = query.Where(p => p.PDF.Equals(SearchString));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing your "Publication PDF" field is some kind of reference field to a media library item. Content of the PDF is in fact not content of your current item. This means that you would need to write a custom computed field that would extract that media library item and crawl its content.

Comment: Correct. Publication PDF is a File Field. Any pointers on how to crawl the PDF content? Im sure I can use the computer field to find the ID of the file, not sure about having to crawl or extract PDF's content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your "Publication PDF" field is some kind of reference field to a media library item. Content of the PDF is in fact not content of your current item. This means that you would need to write a custom computed field that would extract that media library item and crawl its content.

If you want to crawl content of a media item, you might want to use some reflector to check the code of `Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor` class. It's used by Sitecore to get the content of media items, as defined in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`:

```xml
<field fieldName="_content" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor,Sitecore.ContentSearch">
  <mediaIndexing ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/mediaIndexing"/>
</field>
```

You would need to first get media item and then use code copied from this class to get the content of PDF.

**BUT**

Yeah, there is always `but`. If the media library item has changed and your item has not changed, your item will not be reindexed automatically. So if you plan to change pdfs (uploading new item and selecting it should be fine), you would need either think about custom code that would execute reindexing of the item which holds reference to your pdf file, or manually reindex your item.